# Can Excel perform constrained nonlinear optimization?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can Excel perform constrained nonlinear optimization?

Comment: That's the kind of question that gives me total certainty about my ignorance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Excel's Solver](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/introduction-to-optimization-with-the-excel-solver-tool-HA001124595.aspx) to solve nonlinear optimization problems with constraints. Bear in mind that:

> Nonlinear problems are intrinsically
>   more difficult to solve than linear
>   problems, and there are fewer
>   guarantees about what the Solver (or
>   any optimization method) can do. The
>   Solver uses the GRG (Generalized
>   Reduced Gradient)  algorithm -- one of
>   the most robust nonlinear programming
>   methods -- to solve problems whenever
>   the Assume Linear Model box in the
>   Solver Options dialog is unchecked.
>   (When the box is checked, the Solver
>   uses the Simplex method for linear
>   programming problems.) [More...](http://www.solver.com/suppstdnlplimits.htm)

Steps to add the Solver add-in in Excel 2007:

> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
> 2. Click Add-Ins, and then in the Manage box, select Excel Add-ins.
> 3. Click Go.
> 4. In the Add-Ins available box, select the Solver Add-in check box,
>      and then click OK.
>        Tip: If Solver Add-in is not listed in the Add-Ins available box,
>      click Browse to locate the add-in.
>        If you get prompted that the Solver Add-in is not currently
>      installed on your computer, click Yes
>      to install it.
> 5. After you load the Solver Add-in, the Solver command is
>      available in the Analysis group on the
>      Data tab.

This is an [example](http://archives.math.utk.edu/ICTCM/i/12/C023.html) about solving a nonlinear optimization problem using Excel.